# loopback network interface has no IP address

Tags: networking

I can't figure out why my loopback device has no IP address.

Here's /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.33.11.204
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 10.33.1.1
network 10.33.0.0
broadcast 10.33.255.255
dns-nameservers 10.33.3.21 10.33.3.150
```

And here's `ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:99:57:43  
          inet addr:10.33.11.204  Bcast:10.33.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe99:5743/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:597 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:585520 (585.5 KB)  TX bytes:86074 (86.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          LOOPBACK  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

And here's `ip addr show`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:99:57:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.33.11.204/16 brd 10.33.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe99:5743/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What in the world is happening? I have two other servers with similar network configurations and both have 127.0.0.1 as the loopback IP addres.

Comment: I had this really strange case, too. `ifdown lo && ifup lo` fixed it for me, but I still want to know why lo can ever be "up" (couldn't just do `ifup lo`) without having `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Mitja's suggestion fixed it for me.